# Apply conditional logic in IFNULL google data studio

Tags: looker-studio

I have a formula to calculate the NPS score in Google Data Studio, but I also want to apply a logic to it that's it should only calculate the score when the 'Timestamp' is greater than 4/09/2023 (that's where we have time timestamp coming in, before that the timestamp is missing), before that the scorecard should display static value.

I have partially achieved the desired result, it should show static value if the data is missing but if it finds the timestamp and relevant scores it should dynamically calculate the scores for example the dataset could be like

```
Timetamp    score 
              9
              8
              7
14/9/2023     9
20/9/2023     2
```

this is the formula that I have

```
IFNULL((COUNT(CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(How likely are you to recommend this training, "(9|10)") THEN How likely are you to recommend this training
  ELSE NULL
END) / (COUNT(How likely are you to recommend this training) / 100))  - (COUNT(Detractors) / (COUNT(How likely are you to recommend this training) / 100)),70)
```

It works ok, but what I do not want is that when in future, I don't have the scores for a given month, it shouldn't display static as 70 but rather 'No data'